# updating the database after create action doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

`set_bonus(member_id, cookie)` method does not work. I'm trying to update the same model that that the `self.set_signup_attribution(member_id, cookie, origin)` returns.

The `new_has_value` variable returns `{"currency"=>"usd", "type"=>"flat", "amount"=>1000}`

**Model.rb**

```
# THIS METHOD WORKS
def self.set_signup_attribution(member_id, cookie, origin)
  return unless cookie.present?
  tracking_code = cookie
  attribution_channel = AttributionChannel.find_by tracking_code: tracking_code
  associated_member_record = Member.find member_id
  if attribution_channel.present?
    Attribution.create!({
      event: Attribution::SIGN_UP,
      attribution_channel: attribution_channel,
      associated: associated_member_record,
      extra: origin
    })
    set_bonus(member_id, cookie)
  else
    Rails.logger.info "Unknown Attribution Channel for tracking code: '#{ tracking_code }'"
  end
end


# THIS METHOD DOES NOT WORK. UPDATES THE DATABASE.
def self.set_bonus(member_id, cookie)
  epoch = Member.find_by(id: member_id).attribution_epoch
  attribution_code = AttributionChannel.find_by(tracking_code: cookie)
  duration_value = attribution_code.attribution_duration.downcase.split(' ')
  duration = duration_value.first.to_i.send(duration_value.last)
  return if cookie.present? && epoch.present?
  current_time = Time.now
  if attribution_code.bonus_config.present?
    if (current_time - epoch).to_i < duration
      hash_value = attribution_code.bonus_config
      new_hash_value = hash_value.assoc("sign_up")[1]
      value = Attribution.where(attribution_channel_id: attribution_code)
      if new_hash_value["type"] == "flat"
        value.update_all(
          bonus_amount: new_hash_value["amount"],
          bonus_currency: new_hash_value["currency"]
        )
      elsif new_hash_value["type"] == "percentage"
        value.update_all(
          bonus_amount: new_hash_value["amount"],
          bonus_currency: new_hash_value["currency"]
        )
      else
        {
          bonus_amount: "Doesn't exist",
          bonus_currency: "Doesn't exist"
        }
      end
    else
      "Do nothing"
    end
  else
    "Do nothing"
  end
  #cookie = nil
  binding.pry
end
```

**Controller.rb**

```
def index
  unless session[:just_signed_up]
    redirect_back_or_settings_page
  end
  Attribution.set_signup_attribution(current_user, cookies[:visit_attr], request.referer)
  Attribution.set_bonus(current_user, cookies[:visit_attr])
  session[:just_signed_up] = false
  @email = current_user.email
end
```

How do I go about this? That is what I have tried and doesn't work. Can I merge `set_bonus` method to `set_signup_attribution` method or something?

Any help will be appreciated.

**So drilling this further:**

I merged `set_bonus` with `set_signup_attribution` and the two fields (bonus_amount and bonus_currency) which `set_bonus` method is supposed to update returns `nil`:

```
Attribution.create!(
  {
    event: Attribution::SIGN_UP,
    attribution_channel: attribution_channel,
    associated: associated_member_record,
    extra: origin
  }.merge(self.set_bonus(member_id, cookie).to_h)
)
```

With this drill after using `binding.pry` on that `set_bonus` method, I figured out it worked but it's returning `nil` and I don't know why. Could it be because `member_id` is not available in the model or something?

Comment: Is it throwing an error or is it not called?

Comment: I have updated the question @iGian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `if` statement you should call `set_bonus` method on appropriate object.

```
    attribution = Attribution.create!({
      event: Attribution::SIGN_UP,
      attribution_channel: attribution_channel,
      associated: associated_member_record,
      extra: origin
    })
    attribution.set_bonus(member_id, cookie) if attribution.persisted?
```

Just be careful as `.create!` will raise an error in case there is something wrong, so maybe would be better to use

```
  attribution = Attribution.new(.....)
  if attribution.save
    attribution.set_bonus(.....)
  else
    Rails.logger.info  attribution.errors
  end
```

I hope this would help.

Cheers